# For Loop for Bivariate Regressions in Python (with Spreg)

Tags: python, for-loop, regression

I'm trying to create a for loop to run bivariate regression with several explanatory variables. I've created an example where it works fine for an array I create (X, y) below, but when I go from that to a data frame and mimic the output I get with a column from X `[row[0] for row in X]` and for y, and then create a for loop (below, second snipped of code), I get the error `Exception: all input data must be either numpy arrays or sparse csr matrices`. Not sure where I am going wrong or what I am misunderstanding.

```
rng = np.random.RandomState(1)
X = 10 * rng.rand(100, 3)
y = 0.5 + np.dot(X, [1.5, -2., 1.])

# Fit OLS model
for variable in X:
    m1 = spreg.OLS(
        # Dependent variable
        y,
        # Independent variables
        X,
        # Dependent variable name
        name_y="crime_count",
        # Independent variable name
        name_x= ['new', 'else'],
    )

    print(m1.summary)
```

This is what I'm trying to create. crime_demograph is a dataframe.

```
#create a forloop of all bivariate models
variable_names = [
 'kfr_pooled_pooled_p25',
    'bus_count',
    'median_hh_', 
    'population', 
    'per_white',
    'per_black',
    'per_asian',
    'per_latino',
    'per_same_h', 
    'per_same_c', 
    'per_diff_c'
]


# Fit OLS model
for variable in variable_names:
    m1 = spreg.OLS(
        # Dependent variable
        crime_demograph["crime_count"].values,
        # Independent variables
        crime_demograph[variable].values.tolist(),
        # Dependent variable name
        name_y="crime_count",
        # Independent variable name
        name_x= variable_names,
    )

    print(m1.summary)
```

Here are screen shots of the output of the dependent variable and a single explanatory variable which replicate the output of y and a single column of X:
[image]

[image]